# freeing SDL_Surface causes Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, sdl

am using sdl 1.2 for my game project i want to move my surface so i need to free it and re blited with a new position but i everytime i try it with a pointer i get segmentation fault
this is my header.h file:

```
typedef struct {
    SDL_Surface *personnesurface, *score, *vie;
    SDL_Rect position, posscore, posvie;
    int scoretext;
    int vietext;
    TTF_Font *font;
    SDL_Color white;
    char scoretextt[100];
    char vietextt[100];
    double vitesse, acceleration;
} Personne;
```

and this is my code.c where i put all my functions:

```
void
deplacerPerso(Personne *p, Uint32 dt, SDL_Surface *screen)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    int dx;

    dx = (1 / 2) * p->acceleration * (dt * dt) + p->vitesse * dt;
    //printf("%i//",dx);

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_d) {
                SDL_FreeSurface(p->personnesurface);
                p->acceleration += 0.005;
                p->position.x += dx;
                SDL_BlitSurface(p->personnesurface, NULL, screen, &p->position);
            }                           // if key d
            else if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q) {
                p->acceleration -= 0.01;
                p->position.x = dx;
            }                           // if key q
            else if (p->acceleration > 0) {
                p->acceleration -= 0.001;
            }
        }                               // switch event type
    }                                   // while pollevent
}
```

Comment: Side note: `(1/2)*p->acceleration*(dt*dt)` is zero because `1/2` is zero.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: You're doing `SDL_FreeSurface` which frees the surface (i.e. `p->personnesurface` is no longer usable). And then `SDL_BlitSurface` (which tries to use the freed/unusable `p->personnesurface` as the source). If you _must_ free the surface [to get rid of old/stale content], you must recreate a new one to send to the blit. But, I suspect that you just want the blit and _not_ the free. Presumably, [elsewhere] you've _updated_ the contents of `p->personnesurface` with the content for the given frame and just want to copy it to the screen here.

Comment: Not the answer, but why SDL 1.2? SDL 2 exists.

Comment: "i want to move my surface so i need to free it and re blited with a new position" - no, you definitely shouldn't free surface for that. There is no concept on undoing a blit, it just copies pixels, if you don't want your image there anymore - you have to draw something else in the same place. If your question is about that - you'll need to describe your rendering approach in much more detail. For a start, my general hint would be "don't ever render anything in event handler".